# Can't generate signed apk but it works fine

Tags: android, exception, signed-apk, gson

I can run the app and I can use it, but I can't generate signed apk. Here is the log and debug apk is running on some devices only.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class

Here is my app.gradle.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    signingConfigs {

    }
    repositories {
        //jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'http://repo.brightcove.com/releases'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asd.asd"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = [partner: "asd"]
        multiDexEnabled = true

    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_ENABLE_ADS', 'true'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            debuggable true
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile(name: 'MfsAndroidLibrary', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.1.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.3.0'
    compile 'com.brightcove.player:exoplayer:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.useinsider:insider:6.0.8'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.pitt.fresh.library:freshdownloadview:1.0'

    //compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'

    // compile 'com.tkurimura:flickabledialog:0.9.0'

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
    compile 'com.afollestad:sectioned-recyclerview:0.2.3'
    compile 'com.tonicartos:superslim:0.4.13'
    //for select birthday

    compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2'

    //image libraries
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'

    compile 'com.useinsider:insider:6.1.7'

    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.3.0'

    compile 'com.bkm.bexandroidsdk:bexandroidsdk:1.1.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and root gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        flatDir{

            dirs 'libs'
        }
        maven { url "http://mobile.useinsider.com" }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/bkmexpress/maven' }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: The core issue is that some of your dependency is using `gson` with a different version than `2.2.4`. You have to find that dependency and `exclude module: 'gson'` from that dependency.

Comment: I find gson 2.7 in external library but sunsertificationexception when I delete it .

Comment: No don't delete it from external lib. Either you can do this

   `compile('lib using gson 2.7') {` 
                `exclude module: 'gson'` 
            `}`  or just download `gson 2.7 jar` and replace the `2.2.4` . https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I deleted this line

```
 compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
```

added this code and it works

```
compile ('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'){
        transitive = true;
        exclude module: 'gson'
    }
```